# GetPublishingPages using the DefaultView?

Tags: 2007, publishing

I'm pulling a list of pages from a `PublishingWeb` like so

```
...
PublishingWeb pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(elevatedWeb);

foreach (PublishingPage page in pubWeb.GetPublishingPages())
{
    ...
}
...
```

By using a `PublishingPage` I can get the page `Title`, `Description`, `CreatedDate` easily but it sorts on `CreatedDate` ascending (I need descending, but would ultimately prefer using the default view to determine order)

Is there anyway to pull the `DefaultView` of the PublishingPages? I realize these are two different things since `Views` relate to an `SPList` and not a `PublishingPage`.

I can pull in the list instead with something like

```
SPList pages = web.Lists["Pages"];

foreach (SPListItem page in pages.GetItems(pages.DefaultView))
{
    ...
}
```

However, in this case the Title and CreatedDate fields are empty, if I dig deeper in the properties I can get to `vti_title` but feels like I've lost my way digging that far.

Comment: A tip for performance: use `web.GetList("/MyWeb/Lists/Pages")` instead of `web.Lists["Pages"]` http://patil-rajesh.blogspot.com/2011/04/spweblists-vs-spwebgetlist.html